# Transfer ColorFunction from ListContourPlot to ListLIC-Plot

Tags: plotting

I would like to transfer the colors of a ListContourPlot to a ListLIC-Plot.
I tried to interpolate the data of the ListContourPlot and use it as ColorFunction for the second plot but I couldn't get it to work properly, is there a better way to do this?

```
data1 = Table[Sin[i + j^2], {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];
data2 = Table[{Sin[i + j^2], Cos[i + j^2]}, {i, 0, 3, 0.1}, {j, 0, 3, 0.1}];
f = ListInterpolation[data1];
ListContourPlot[data1, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow"]
ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot[data2, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n},
ColorData["DarkRainbow"][f[x, y]]], RasterSize -> 100]
```

I get the following error:

```
InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {0.,0.} lies outside the range of
data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used. >> 
...
```

The result should look remotely like the following
[image: plot]

Comment: hat do you mean by "transfer the colors"?

Comment: I would like to color the ListLIC-Plot exacly like the ContourPlot. Basically overlaying the ListLIC-Plot with the ContourPlot plot. I add an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You need to set `ColorFunctionScaling -> False`, otherwise the $x$ and $y$ passed into your `ColorFunction` are rescaled to lie between 0 and 1 instead of having their original values.
2. There's a discrepancy between how `ListContourPlot` and `ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot` interpret the dimensions of the input arrays as $x$ and $y$ coordinates. So to get the image you say you want, you have to use `f[y, x]` in the `ColorFunction`. Still, I think it's quite likely that the image you *actually* want is the one with `f[x, y]`, because then the colours correspond to the $x$-component of the velocity field as one might expect from the definitions of `data1` and `data2`.
3. Finally, we have to rescale `f` to a $[0,1]$ range manually, say using `Rescale`, before passing it into `ColorData`.

```
ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot[data2, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
   ColorData["DarkRainbow"][Rescale[f[y, x], {-1, 1}]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, RasterSize -> 100]
```

[image]

You still get *InterpolationFunction::dmval* warnings, but at least you get the desired plot.

P.S. The plot I think you actually want, with `f[x, y]` instead of `f[y, x]`:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
l1 = ListContourPlot[data1, ColorFunction -> "DarkRainbow", Frame -> False, 
                     PlotRange -> {{1.`, 31.`}, {1.`, 31.`}}, ContourStyle -> None];
l2 = ListLineIntegralConvolutionPlot[data2, ColorFunction -> GrayLevel, Frame -> False, 
                     PlotRange -> {{1.`, 31.`}, {1.`, 31.`}}];
ImageCompose[l2, {l1, .5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]